# My Spline animation in React, zooms in and out when i scroll with the mouse

Tags: reactjs, spline

It's been a while I am trying to make my Spline viewer component in the same size while I scroll in my website, however even if I turned off all the zoom effects in the settings of export, I still can not control the annimation:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TypeAnimation} from 'react-type-animation';
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';
import {fadeIn} from '../variants';
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import Loading from './Loading';
const Spline = React.lazy(() => import('@splinetool/react-spline'));
const Banner = () => {
  return (
    <section className='h-screen pb-10 container mx-auto  flex items-center' id='home'>
      <div className='flex-col relative container flex  justify-between h-screen items-center'>
        <div className='flex w-full self-center flex-col justify-center'>
          <div className='text-center'>
            <motion.h1 variants={fadeIn('up, 0.3')} initial="hidden" whileInView={'show'} viewport={{ once: false, amount: 0.7 }} className='text-[4rem] mb-[5rem]'>Hello World!</motion.h1>
    
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='absolute h-screen w-screen mb-10 my-3 flex items-center justify-center'>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <Spline
          className=''
            scene="https://prod.spline.design/BSToMHfvR0DfJewQ/scene.splinecode"
          />
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Banner;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before but with Vite + Vue. Updates made to the spline model play settings are usually reflected with a quick refresh, but sometimes you have to clear your browser cache.

> Clear your browser cache